# BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN not working intermittently

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-erp

We are facing one issue where the work order is not getting cancelled in production environment. This is happening intermittently. We have used BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN for cancelling the work orders. Also, the BAPI is not returning any error messages. We tried to replicate this issue in test environment with the same data. But work order in test environment was cancelled successfully. Is there anything can be done to expose the exact problem occurring in the BAPI? Please note that this issue is occurring intermittently and the frequency is not that concerning!

Comment: You need to analyse which factors influence BAPI execution in prod and in test, simulate the same data, the same highload, etc. Just usual troubleshooting work.

Comment: Thank you for your input. We have tried all of the stuffs except high load. Also please note that this issue is coming intermittently during processing of individual records and not during bulk processing.

Comment: What returns `return` parameter? Give the code how you call it for bulk and for individual